# How to check if new directory can be created on specified path?

Tags: python, directory

How to check if new directory can be created on specified path?
I have access restriction for few windows paths and new directory can not be crated at such locations.
I have tried with following approach of using os.access to check different access types and all returns TRUE whereas new directory can not be created at this location. How to check this kind of access?
[image]

```
`path = C:\Program Files (x86)
if os.access(path, os.X_OK):
    print(path, ":X_OK:", os.access(path, os.X_OK))
    print(path, ":F_OK:", os.access(path, os.F_OK))
    if os.access(path, os.R_OK) and os.access(path, os.W_OK):
      print(path, ":R_OK:", os.access(path, os.R_OK))
      print(path, ":W_OK:", os.access(path, os.W_OK))
      return True`
This gives following output:
C:\Program Files (x86) :X_OK: True
C:\Program Files (x86) :F_OK: True
C:\Program Files (x86) :R_OK: True
C:\Program Files (x86) :W_OK: True
```

Comment: Acc to documentation for [os.access](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), you should use ```try except``` blocks for this.
"Note I/O operations may fail even when access() indicates that they would succeed, particularly for operations on network filesystems which may have permissions semantics beyond the usual POSIX permission-bit model."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are checking all of these permissions, and they all return True. This means that the current user has read, write, and execute permissions to the path C:\Program Files (x86). However, this does not guarantee that the user has permission to create a new directory in this location.

To check if the user has permission to create a new directory, you can use the os.mkdir() function. This function will raise an OSError exception if the user does not have the necessary permissions.

```
def can_create_dir(path):
 
  try:
    os.mkdir(path)
    return True
  except OSError:
    return False
```

Another way is to use the win32security module in Python. This module provides functions for getting and setting the security permissions on files and directories.

```
def can_create_dir(path):

  dacl = win32security.GetFileSecurity(path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
  if dacl is None:
    return False

  for ace in dacl.GetAces():
    if ace.GetAccessMask() & win32security.WRITE_DAC:
      return True

  return False
```

Comment: def can_create_dir(path):
 
  try:
    os.mkdir(path)
    return True
  except OSError:
    return False

Using this is the quickest and simplest way.